# Distribution Upgrade CRASH/FREEZE

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

Here's my situation: just got a new computer with Ubuntu 12.04. It suggested an upgrade to 14.04. I ran the upgrade and it already crashed once, so I had to restore system to its original state. Now, after I fixed everything, I ran the distribution upgrade again and it froze AGAIN. Its in the ''Installing the upgrades'' phase, ''unpacking adium-theme-ubuntu''. It just hangs, like not responding. I'm writing here, because I'm hoping to save this situation without having to quit the upgrade and having a broken system. NOTE that I am completely new with Linux and Ubuntu. At the moment I'm just gonna let it hang, even if it takes all night. Don't know how to solve this, please help!